# UisearchBar with Custom Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, search

In my app, I implemented search bar with the scope. 
Also the scope bar is also not hidden by `searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;` property
How should I change it?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502166/help-with-search-bar-scope-buttons